# Detailed C++ book for a programmer already familiar with C and object-oriented programming?

Tags: learning, c++, books

I know (to some extent) a few languages, including C, Java and Python. I'm also (somewhat) familiar with Scala and Scheme, plus I can read (but not write) x86 Assembly. Say I want to learn C++, what is a good book which doesn't try to teach me what a class is, teach me inheritance, polymorphism or loosely coupled classes again, nor does try to teach me other basics, just the C++ language (as well as how to write *idiomatic* C++ code, not e.g. Java with C++ syntax) and its standard library?

**Note:** "Detailed" as used in the title means that it doesn't try to cover C++ in 100 pages, I want to know the details of the language. Of course, mastery comes from practice, but I don't want to learn just a little bit of C++ from the book, but learn it quite thoroughly.

Comment: An important question for me, too. I just found out that my new project is mostly or entirely C++ when I really went straight from ten years of C to (nearly) ten years of C#.

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for the definitive C++ book list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a quick start:
[Accelerated c++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) is very good - it uses with modern c++ concepts, rather than with 'C'type stuff

You should also get [effective c++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201924889) or check the c++ faq site.

Finally it's big and comprehensive, [Stroustrups C++ programming language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201700735).

Answer (score 4):

Bruce Eckel's Thinking in C++ is very good IMHO.

Comment: I agree, Eckel's book would be my first recommendation for someone with a good C background. Koenig and Moo's "Accelerated C++" is my top recommendation for learning C++ without much programming background.

Comment: I thought "thinking in c++" was too much of a learn to program book - it's about OO with c++ as the example

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Primer Plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672326973)

[The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201379260)

Yes.